# How to establish two-way communication between a RaspberryPi and remotely hosted Webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, raspberry-pi

Hello to you great people,

I have more of a 'conceptual' question rather than a purely code-oriented one.

So I have Node.js and Express running on my RPI. I can connect to the board from a computer in the same local area and turn a single LED on and off remotely.

What I'd like to do next is host the web interface on Heroku for example and access the 'functionality' of my RPI from the web rather than from a local connection.

- How does one go about doing so? Are there any projects which I can
  draw inspiration from?
- Should I somehow use web-sockets to establish communication
  between the two?
- How do I send a 'request' from the server to the RPI, which has a
  local IP behind the router?
- What is a framework or a set of frameworks that might help me achieve that? (SocketIO?)

So... How does the 'internet of things' work really? How do you control a device from the internet and how do you send input from the device to a web interface?

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to reply!

Comment: It sounds like you're already doing what you want.  You're turning an LED off and on with your application.  What more is there?

Comment: does your kit include http functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I would use socket.io. 
It's a great library for websockets.
http://socket.io/

Comment: Oh, I see you've mentioned it in your post. Anyway, I think that's the way to go, if you need simple 2-way communication.

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on how you want to connect.  Two way communication can be as simple as rest communication being permitted on both ends.  If you need continuous communication you can use websockets or direct tcp communication, etc.  If you want just a status update on the website, you can have the device be the rest host.  You send a request to `{device.ip}/led/on` and the device turns on, or `/status` and it will tell you what lights are on, etc.  The web user would be a simple client which could even be hosted directly on the raspberry pi if you don't need a lot of clients connected simultaneously.  It really depends on your application and what purpose/frequency you need to communicate.

Some good resources for a node.js rest framework:

- ExpressJS: A nodejs application framework
  http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html NodeJS Websocket: A
- websocket library for nodejs
  https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket